# How to load images in express js hosted on vercel

Tags: node.js, express, vercel

I am trying to make a GitHub banner generator using express js, my code works fine locally but when I try to host it on vercel all the image files go missing and I get `no such file or directory found` error.

```
app.get('/api',async(req,res)=>{

    const title = req.query.title || "Github Banner Generator"
    const subTitle = req.query.subtitle || ""
    
    const theme = req.query.theme || "default"

    const _theme = require(`./themes/${theme}/${theme}.json`)

    const image = await loadImage(fs.readFileSync('themes/default/image1.png'))

    const img = await new Canvas(1280, 520)
    .printImage(image,0,0)
    .setColor(_theme.primaryColor)
    .setTextFont('bold 60px Serif')
    .setTextAlign('center')
    .printText(title,1280/2,520/2)
    .setTextFont('20px Serif')
    .setTextAlign('center')
    .printText(subTitle,1280/2,(520/2)+60)
    .toBuffer();

    res.set({'Content-Type':'image/png'})
    res.send(img)
})
```

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the image path isn't right because of you didn't used an absolute path. You should read more about [the difference between `./` and `__dirname` in NodeJS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-__dirname-and-in-node-js/).

My solution would be to use `__dirname + (the file location depending on the current file folder)`

```js
const image = await loadImage(fs.readFileSync(__dirname 
+ '/themes/default/image1.png'));
```

Here, I assume that your project structure looks something like this...

```
/package.json
/index.js (contains the code)
/themes/default/image1.png
```

Comment: "Maybe you could try this..." in an answer?   Are you _really_ trying to give an answer, then please share info on why this should be _tried_.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't sure of this because of the path of the image that could be somewhere else depending on `__dirname`. I understand what you mean and will be aware of it in the future.